# How to programmatically read items from a VSS backup drive?

Tags: .net, powershell, volume-shadow-service

I use VSS to backup to a backup drive. I'd like attach that drive on another machine and list all the backups on it and then list all the items within a particular backup.

I know you can do it at the command prompt with the `wbadmin` tool using `wbadmin get versions` and `wbadmin get items` but I'd like to read the values programmatically.

I know that there are [powershell commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706683.aspx) for working with VSS but they seem to only work with a local 'Policy' object. I can't find a way to examinine a disk from another machine (with a different Policy). For example the Get-WBBackupTarget doesn't have a parameter to point it at my backup drive letter, only a Policy object. And Get-WBPolicy only returns the current Policy for the system afaik.

So is it possible to read information from a backup drive programmatically?

Comment: i think you can have access to your drive by using a network share then use the cmdlets

Comment: @Kayasax A network share isn't an option in my environment

Answer (score 0):

did you try get-wbdisks ?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706673.aspx

> Detailed Description The Get-WBDisks cmdlet gets the list of internal
>   and external disks that are online for the local computer. The disks
>   that you get can be added to the backup policy (WBPolicy object) using
>   the New-WBBackupTarget cmdlet to specify them as backup storage
>   locations.